# How to change the color of the jumbotron? Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, background-color

I've got a problem on changing the color of the jumbotron in Bootstrap3, I tried creating another class just to change the color of it, I also tried overriding the existing class and change the background color but doesn't change. What's the best way to solve this problem? By the way, here is my code!

Nevermind the bootstrap library,

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p> 
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p> 
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS** (external)

```
.jumbotron{
width: 1150px;
height: 320px;
background-color: #E64545;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code of your css links in the `head` tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the background-color of jumbrotron?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904102/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-jumbrotron)

Answer (score 1):

Don't overwrite Bootstrap classes, just add one like this:

```
.myJumbotron {
   background-color: #E64545;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron myJumbotron">
  <p>This is another paragraph.</p> 
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> 
  <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1d9dL2zo/)

Comment: Updated with jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/1d9dL2zo/